# How to read system environment variable in php-fpm?

Tags: php, nginx, environment-variables

Nginx + php-fpm + yii

I have system environment variable with DB connection string

```
$ cat '~/.bashrc'
export DB_CONNECTION="connection_string"
```

Set it in the php-fpm config

```
$ cat /etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
env[DB_CONNECTION] = $DB_CONNECTION
```

Trying to use in my PHP code

```
<?php
var_dump(getenv('DB_CONNECTION'));
```

Got

```
string(0) ""
```

If i hardcode it in php-fpm config

```
$ cat /etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
env[DB_CONNECTION] = "connection_string"
```

It works:

```
<?php
var_dump(getenv('DB_CONNECTION'));
```

```
string(17) "connection_string"
```

How to make php-fpm read actual system environment variable?

Comment: Have you tried `env[DB_CONNECTION] = ${DB_CONNECTION}`? I don't know if it would work, but that's the syntax for [php.ini](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php). I'm not sure if the fpm pool configs are parsed as root, but if your bashrc is in a different user's home directory that might also be a problem.

Comment: At least on php 8.1, adding braces does not work. Indeed, it does make php-fpm not even start...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a PHP Package to handle your environment variables?
Laravel uses https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv

I suggest you use that, and since you are using Yii that means you have composer installed.

`composer require vlucas/phpdotenv`

Comment: using .env works in most scenarios, but not f.e. when you want to pass to php the value of APP_ENV, as that variable is _used_ by the dotenv component itself, to locate the env file(s) to load - at least symfony/dotenv does...